# Can a windows service be used on a Silverlight website?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-services

OK sorry for my bad question.well my project is a asp site that a user can listen to music from and upload music to a db.when a user uploads music the windows service must send an email to tell the users of the new music.

Well all that i want to know is can i use a windows service to send the emails? from a few answers earlier,i saw it may be a security risk. i just want to know if i can use a windows service for this or what should i use to send the emails?

Comment: You'll have to tell us what you mean by "used". Of course a win service can be accessed over IP, and must be installed... but what are you really trying to do?

Comment: And it must allow the access (i.e. open a network port).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question makes no sense from whatever direction.

First, there is no such thing as a silverlight website. A website is just HTML and is hosted on IIS (or an alternative like Apache) and silverlight is a client side technology. Just because you load silverlight into a page does not make it a silverlight website.

A windows service is like any other program and can access the network if it is designed to do so. What do you think IIS is? It's just a service

> so im guessing a website wouldnt install it automatically?

Basic misunderstanding here what "a website" is. Sure a website will not automatically break security and install software on a normally secured server, although it may try on a badly configured one (after all, with proper configuration running as admin it can make any call locally into the server it wants).

Basically, when you want software on the server, install it. A windows service is nothing more than a program, it can be like ISS, exchange, or any other server software you can imagine.

Seems some beginner books into how modern operating systems operate, how IIS and all are operating on a glocal level are in order?

Answer (score 1):

there is usually no way a web hosting company would allow you to install a windows service on their servers. A windows service requires to be always running and is installed on the machine permanently, very different approach than an hosted IIS web application which could be linked to its own application pool but is still handled by IIS and allows the hosting company to have many of them in the same virtual or real server.

an hosted application (SL in your case) can communicate with a windows service regardless where the service is installed via WCF, for example, as long as the IP address or machine name where the service runs is known to the SL application.

Answer (score 0):

A Windows service can be used on the server side from the website but you'll have to have some kind of interface to it. Silverlight is running on the client side so if you need to communicate with a Windows service, you'll have to implement that communication yourself. It's not likely that a Windows service would be directly accessible from outside the server (usually that's a security risk, unless the service is specifically designed to be accessed remotely). If it doesn't have a remote access interface, you'll have to put some kind of front-end in place that can be called by your Silverlight code and that will forward calls to the service.